# Package "mdframed" creating arbitrary gaps in the border

Tags: environments, mdframed

I used to define a small environment with the package "mdframed". I've included the package in the following way:

```
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
```

This is how I've set up the environment:

```
\newenvironment{bspbox}
  [2]
  {\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=gray!25, innerleftmargin=3pt, innerrightmargin=3pt, leftmargin=5pt, rightmargin=5pt, skipabove=5pt, skipbelow=5pt, linewidth=0pt, frametitle={Title#2: #1}, frametitlefont=\normalfont\bfseries]}
  {\end{mdframed}}
```

It works okay, but unfortunately, there are some arbitrarily placed gaps interrupting the line / frame. They can appear in various places, but in most cases, it looks like in the following screenshot: 
[image: mdframed-environment]

The environment was used in my document in the following way:

```
\begin{bspbox}{}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{bspbox}
```

To sum it all up, this is what the MWE looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{xcolor} % mehr vordefinierte Farben
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows,trees,positioning,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{bspbox}
  [2]
  {\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=gray!25, innerleftmargin=3pt, innerrightmargin=3pt, leftmargin=5pt, rightmargin=5pt, skipabove=5pt, skipbelow=5pt, linewidth=0pt, frametitle={Title#2: #1}, frametitlefont=\normalfont\bfseries]}
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{bspbox}{}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{bspbox}

\end{document}
```

Where lies my fault, why are there those arbitrary gaps interrupting the line?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please follow Jubobs request of providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  As it stands your options to `mdframed` contain `linewidth=0pt` which produces no frame at all.  If I change that to `1pt` then I do not see the describe behaviour in a minimal document.

Comment: Might also be an idea to list which version of `mdframed` you are using.

Comment: Your MWE does not produce the posted image.  See my previous comment about `linewidth`.  As daleif says, telling us the version numbers of the packages you are using could also be helpful; you can get these by adding `\listfiles` to your preamble, they will be printed in the log file.

Comment: I know it may sound weird, but including `\listfiles` in my preamble actually _removed_ the gap!

Anyway, this is the crucial part of the logfile: `Package: mdframed 2012/04/08 v1.5: mdframed`

Comment: As Andrew says, your MWE does not produce your image, please post exactly the code that gives the problem. And setting `linewidth` to something non-zero gives the expected frame. I'm using version `2013/07/01 1.9b` so I;d suggest updating you LaTeX installation